# Asp.Net Core Api Default Routing

Tags: asp.net-core, routes

I have a very basic Asp.Net Core Api; my controller looks like this:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public IEnumerable<Resource> Test(string id)
    {
         // Breakpoint here
    }
```

I would expect the following URL to invoke the method, and fire the breakpoint:

```
https://localhost:5012/test/test/1
```

However, it doesn't. In fact, the following URL does:

```
https://localhost:5012/test/1
```

I was under the impression that the format for the URL was as follows (from startup):

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

So, unless that action is `Index`:

```
https://localhost:5012/controller/action/id
```

But it appears that the accepted format is:

```
https://localhost:5012/controller/id
```

My question is, why is this?

Comment: by specifying attribute with value "{id}", you override default behaviour. Remove attribute and use "/test/test/1"

Comment: I tried that initially, but it made no difference

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Conventional Routing in ASP.NET Core API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60205552/conventional-routing-in-asp-net-core-api)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [pwrigshihanomoronimo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60247637/12906483) answer,

you can just change this

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public IEnumerable<Resource> Test(string id)
```

to

```
[HttpGet("[action]/{id}")]
public IEnumerable<Resource> Test(string id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is `ApiController` attribute, who breaks your routing. Looks like `app.UseEndpoints` configures routes just for MVC. So the solution is to remove all attributes to have the following code

```
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
    public string Test(string id)
    {
        return "OK";
    }
}
```

Or, if you want to keep `ApiController` attribute, you would need to adjust `Route` value as well. You can remove `app.UseEndpoints`, if you don't use MVC in your project

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]/[action]")]
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public string Test(string id)
    {
        return "OK";
    }
}
```