# Conventional Routing doesn't deserialize json body requests (ASP.NET Core API)

Tags: json, asp.net-core, .net-core, routes, asp.net-apicontroller

**Problem**

Using ApiControllerAttribute and RouteAttribute on controllers and actions, everythings work fine.

When I change the code to work with Convetional Routing, the Identity property in request is always set to null.

**Code with ApiControllerAttribute (Identity loaded in request)**

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
Public Class Main : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost(nameof(GetExternalRemoteExternal))]
    public async Task<GetByIdentityResponse<RemoteExternal>> GetExternalRemoteExternal(GetByIdentityRequest<RemoteExternalIdentity> request)
    {
        return await GetExternal<RemoteExternal, RemoteExternalIdentity>(request);
    }
}
```

*startup.cs*

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => endpoints.MapControllers());
```

**Code with Convetional Routing (request has null Identity)**

```
Public Class Main : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<GetByIdentityResponse<RemoteExternal>> GetExternalRemoteExternal(GetByIdentityRequest<RemoteExternalIdentity> request)
    {
        return await GetExternal<RemoteExternal, RemoteExternalIdentity>(request);
    }
}
```

*startup.cs*

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                                               name: "default",
                                               pattern: "api/{controller}/{action}")) //Not work even with "api/{controller}/{action}/{?id}"
```

**Common code**

```
public class GetByIdentityRequest<TIDentity> : ServiceRequest
    where TIDentity : BaseIdentity
{
    public TIDentity Identity { get; set; }
}

public class RemoteExternalIdentity : BaseIdentity
{
    public int IdX { get; set; }
}
```

**JSON**

`{"$id":"1","Identity":{"$id":"2","IdX":10000}}`

**API LINK**

`.../api/Main/GetExternalRemoteExternal`

Comment: Can you show the annotations of your controller? Also, what URLs are you using to make the requests?

Comment: Try putting a `[FromBody]` before the parameter type `GetByIdentityRequest<RemoteExternalIdentity>`. The `[ApiController]` attribute adds a few conventions which may cause the difference here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`[ApiController]` attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#apicontroller-attribute) adds a few conventions to controllers that enables some opinionated behaviors, including [binding source parameter inference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#binding-source-parameter-inference) that will make complex parameters bind from the body by default.

Since you cannot use the `[ApiController]` attribute with convention-based routing (since one of the convention is to prevent exactly that), you can use an explicit `[FromBody]` with your parameters to force them to be parsed from the JSON body:

```
public class Main : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<GetByIdentityResponse<RemoteExternal>> GetExternalRemoteExternal(
        [FromBody] GetByIdentityRequest<RemoteExternalIdentity> request)
    {
        return await GetExternal<RemoteExternal, RemoteExternalIdentity>(request);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation. I scratched my head for about 1 hour before I looked up the solution and found your solution. (Y)